# cdc_raw folder is empty in cassandra docker

Tags: docker, cassandra

I am using cassandra 3.11.11 inside Docker. I have enabled `cdc_enabled to true` and then tried create to keyspace and table with below commands.

```
CREATE KEYSPACE abc WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 1};
CREATE TABLE abc.foo (a int, b text, PRIMARY KEY(a)) WITH cdc=true;
INSERT INTO abc.foo(a,b) VALUES(1,'ABCD');
```

I don't know the reason but commit log files are not getting created under cdc_raw folder.

Tried similar set up with the same version in local and i can see commit log files are getting created under cdc_raw.

Answer (score 0):

If you only inserted a single row - then it is unlikely that it would appear in the cdc_raw folder.

The commit log segment needs to be completed and then a memtable flush occur of all items in the commit log segment, so that it can be released. (Otherwise the writes would not be able to be replayed in the event of a crash, and without the flush, the log remains the durable entry of the mutation.)

If just testing some specific things around CDC, I normally would lower the `commitlog_segment_size_in_mb` (as long as mutations are not > half the size) and manually perform a `nodetool flush`.